# In Keras, how obtain the same accuracy value of evaluate method by predict method?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

Firstly, I followed the example coded in [Tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns)

and make the codes below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import feature_column
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/applied-dl/heart.csv'
dataframe = pd.read_csv(URL)
dataframe.head()

train, test = train_test_split(dataframe, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)

def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  dataframe = dataframe.copy()
  labels = dataframe.pop('target')
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  return ds

batch_size = 32
train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

feature_columns = []

age = feature_column.numeric_column("age")

# numeric cols
for header in ['age', 'trestbps', 'chol', 'thalach', 'oldpeak', 'slope', 'ca']:
  feature_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column(header))

# bucketized cols
age_buckets = feature_column.bucketized_column(age, boundaries=[18, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65])
feature_columns.append(age_buckets)

# indicator cols
thal = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      'thal', ['fixed', 'normal', 'reversible'])
thal_one_hot = feature_column.indicator_column(thal)
feature_columns.append(thal_one_hot)

# embedding cols
thal_embedding = feature_column.embedding_column(thal, dimension=8)
feature_columns.append(thal_embedding)

# crossed cols
crossed_feature = feature_column.crossed_column([age_buckets, thal], hash_bucket_size=1000)
crossed_feature = feature_column.indicator_column(crossed_feature)
feature_columns.append(crossed_feature)

feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_ds,
          validation_data=val_ds,
          epochs=5)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_ds)
print("Accuracy", accuracy)

# Try to use predict to get the same accuracy
predictions = model.predict(test_ds)
for i, p in enumerate(predictions):
  print(p, test.iloc[i,-1])
```

After executed, I obtained the Accuracy = 0.6885246.

Then, I try to use `predict` method to get the predictions of the evaluated dataset, but the result I got in `print(p, test.iloc[i,-1]` is:

```
[-1.7059733] 0
[-0.914219] 0
[2.6422875] 1
[-0.50430596] 1
[-1.2348572] 0
[-0.57301724] 0
[-2.1014583] 0
[-4.370711] 0
[0.21761642] 0
[-2.8065221] 0
[-3.2469923] 0
[-0.25715744] 1
[0.05394493] 1
[1.2391514] 0
[-3.7102253] 1
[-4.0611124] 0
[1.36385] 0
[-1.1096503] 0
[3.4140522] 1
[0.6951326] 0
[-3.232728] 0
[0.98346126] 0
[0.04960524] 0
[-0.90004027] 0
[1.918218] 0
[-0.02936329] 0
[-0.55671084] 1
[-2.1650188] 1
[-4.8975983] 0
[-1.5514184] 1
[-2.1743653] 0
[0.56928] 0
[-2.8607953] 0
[2.4095147] 0
[0.5155109] 1
[0.7517127] 0
[-1.6738821] 0
[-3.733505] 0
[2.2426589] 1
[-2.6165645] 0
[-2.1079547] 0
[-1.8746301] 0
[-4.116344] 0
[0.33854234] 1
[-2.3230617] 0
[-0.02075209] 1
[-0.33064234] 0
[1.6755556] 1
[1.1898655] 1
[0.40846193] 0
[-0.33131325] 0
[-0.63726294] 0
[-2.7144134] 0
[-0.48318636] 0
[1.516653] 1
[2.5299337] 1
[-2.1182806] 0
[-2.5583768] 1
[-0.65298045] 1
[-1.4936553] 0
[-0.7257029] 0
```

My question is what method I should use to convert the float result to binary (0 or 1) and compare the target? My ultimate goal is to obtain the accuracy value 0.6885246 obtained by evaluate method.

Edit after obtained solution:

1. change to "from_logits=false"
2. change output layer "layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')"
3. add the following codes after model.predict

```
final_preds = [1 if x>0.5 else 0 for x in predictions]
m = 0
for i, p in enumerate(final_preds):
   if p == test.iloc[i, -1]
      m += 1

print(m / len(final_preds))
```

After run, I got:

```
Accuracy 0.6885246
0.6885245901639344
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very surprised with this recent fashion in Tensorflow tutorials to go with a linear activation function in the model last layer (`Dense(1)`) for *classification* problems, and then ask for `from_logits=True` in the loss function. I guess the reason is that it may lead to better numeric stability, as claimed in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy):

> **`from_logits`**: Whether to interpret `y_pred` as a tensor of [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) values.
>   By default, we assume that `y_pred` contains probabilities (i.e., values
>   in [0, 1]). Note: Using `from_logits=True` may be more numerically
>   stable.

Where "by defaul" means that the default value of the loss function argument here is `from_logits=False`.

In any case, you have ended up with predictions of *logits*, and not probabilities as was normally the case so far in similar tutorials (and in practice). And the problem with logits is exactly that they lack an intuitive interpretation, in contrast with probabilistic predictions.

What you should do is pass your logits from a sigmoid function to convert them to probabilities:

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
```

Example with your first four predictions:

```
preds = np.array([-1.7059733, -0.914219, 2.6422875, -0.50430596])
sigmoid(preds)
# array([0.15368673, 0.28613728, 0.93353404, 0.37652929])
```

and then convert them to "hard" predictions with a threshold of 0.5:

```
final_preds = [1 if x>0.5 else 0 for x in preds]
final_preds
# [0, 0, 1, 0]
```

and in this form you can compare them with the ground truth.

But what I would suggest you to consider instead in order to avoid this, is change your last layer to

```
Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
```

and remove the `(from_logits=True)` argument from the loss definition. That way the `model.predict` should return the hard predictions (not tested).